# How to duplicate data written to a http response .pdf file?

Tags: c#, pdf, localreport

I am trying to duplicate the text written to a .pdf file (http response).
For example:
I'm writing two datasources to a pdf file, I need to duplicate it three times (so there are 4 pages in de .pdf file instead of 1).
Currently the data is written to the file as following (not all lines of set parameters are below):

```
reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(header);
reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(body);
reportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);

byte[] bytes;

bytes = reportViewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);

Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = mimeType;
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + name + "." + extension);
Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
Response.End();
```

I need the following data in the .pdf file:

page 1: header and body

page 2: header and body

page 3: header and body

page 4: header and body

I couldn't duplicate the following code three times:

```
bytes = reportViewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);
```

How could I get the four pages in the .pdf file?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

- Open PDF using third party lib prior to writing
- Copy desired pages as many times as needed or wrap them in XOBject and add references to this XOBject from new pages
- Write the response

I use [Apitron PDF Kit library](http://apitron.com/Product/pdf-kit) for my PDF processing tasks, but there are many of them available free and paid.